# How do i keep my button hidden when specific conditions are met?

Tags: ios, uibutton

Please can you help me, I am new to programing and need a little bit of help.
I am trying to cause a button called “rearmbutton” to stay hidden when the following condition is met:

```
_currentData.heartrate > 0
```

I have tried to implement this into my code where there are different conditions already in place that keep this button hidden without any success. 
I have searched about without much luck at finding a solution which is why I am now here asking for help.

I have checked the code that keeps the button hidden before changing it and confirmed that the button does stay hidden when the conditions are met.

With my addition to the code, my application malfunctions and the button does not stay hidden, instead it becomes stuck in its visible state.

Here is what I have completed so far, you can see in the 6th line from the bottom I have already tried to use the code, but it is not working, please can you explain where i am going wrong and how i might fix this please:

```
//////////////////////////////
// COOLDOWN - we are cooling down from an event -> no alarm

if (_coolDownPeriod > 0 && [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] < _coolDownPeriod) {
    DLog(@"Cooling down");
    _shouldAlarm = NO;

    int time = (int) (_coolDownPeriod - [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]);

    int min  = floor((float) time / 60.0);
    int sec  = time - (60*min);

    _timeLeftInCoolDownLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Time left until rearmed: %.2d:%.2d", min, sec];
    _rearmButton.hidden = NO;


} else {

    if (_currentData.heartrate > 0) _timeLeftInCoolDownLabel.text = @"";
    _rearmButton.hidden = YES;
    DLog(@"Rearm Hidden")


}
```

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrapping the `if` condition within `{}` will fix i guess

```
if (_currentData.heartrate > 0)
{ 
  _timeLeftInCoolDownLabel.text = @"";
  _rearmButton.hidden = YES;
  DLog(@"Rearm Hidden")
}
```

Comment: The question is bit confusing, if this not what you intended let me know and make your points clear

Comment: Hi @Anil, sorry for the question, it was very hard to explain what i am trying to achieve but your answer was on track of what i was looking for, so thank you. I have tried your answer, this does stop the app from malfunctioning, however the button is still staying visible when the condition for heartrate > 0 is met.

Comment: Put a break point within that if condition and check block is executing

Comment: i tried this, it would seem that the condition is being met at the very start of the app instead of when 0 heartrate is found. What i expect is happening is that the other condition in the code _timeLeftInCoolDownLabel.text = @""; is always being triggered as there is no text in that area until _coolDownPeriod is activated, does this make sense?

Comment: I tried removing the code: '_timeLeftInCoolDown.text = @"";' and ran the app again however the break point is still being triggered at: 'if (_currentData.heartrate > 0)' even though the heartrate is actually at 80. i tried changing the code to: 'if (_currentData.heartrate == 0)' but this also did not work.

Comment: If that is the case put `_timeLeftInCoolDownLabel.text = @"";` out side of if block.

Comment: 80 is grater than 0 so if condition will execute

Comment: i see, what i am trying to achieve is if heartrate is 0 and only 0 the condition will trigger.

Comment: So you wanna hide the button if heartrate is 0 right?

Comment: Thn if (_currentData.heartrate == 0) should work. try to NSLog your heartrates and make sure it is becoming 0 at some point

Comment: Thanks, good to know i was on the right track, i have been using NSLog on the heart rates, the very first heart rate that is logged is 0, but interestingly the breakpoint triggered not on the first heart rate of 0 but on the second which states 80. i ran a second test and the first heart rate was 80 but this also triggered the break point.

Comment: also, with the code ' if (_currentData.heartrate == 0) ' the app goes back to the original malfunction in the original problem.

Comment: Unfortunately the code is too long to put into a comment, here is a small chunk of the code that i have altered: 'if (_currentData.heartrate == 0) { _rearmButton.hidden = YES; DLog(@"Rearm Hidden") }'

Comment: Sorry, forgot to say about the malfunction, basically instead of hiding the button, the button stays visible while the app continues working in the back ground, normally once pressed the button would hide again, but with the alteration to the code the button does not hide at all after being pressed.

Comment: I really want to help you. But this out of my thoughts since i dont know what you are trying to achieve and iam quite sure that not lies in these two lines of code. Several other lines of code or logic leading you

Comment: i understand, i also agree that it is not in the few lines of code that i have put up, there is more code to this method but unfortunately i cannot put that amount of code into a comment, is there another way of discussing this where i would be able to make more clear what i am trying to achieve and show you where i think the problems lie?

Comment: UPDATE - i have been trying a few more things here and have discovered from the logs where the problem is, however to explain in a clear manor is going to be very difficult in the comments section, could you suggest a way we could talk where i would be able to write in detail what i have found and where i am now at? would to best way to be to make a new question?

Comment: We cannot chat here since you don't have enough reputation. You can reach me anilvarghese890@gmail.com if you want. You can edit the same queestion here with the more clarification or if the problem is something else you can ask a new question, will get the attention of more developers. Dont ask the same question they will close it. Also pass me the link here will try to help you